# On API version 39 and trying to create trigger on Custom Object

Tags: trigger, custom, object

Any idea or if it is even possible to create triggers on custom objects in SalesForce now? I know in the past we could add triggers through the develop menu and now triggers have to be added through the actual object you want to create the trigger on. Do we have to do this through Eclipse or some other third party?

Comment: To my knowledge nothing has changed. You can still directly create triggers through the UI, Dev Console, or the IDE (In sandbox or DE of course). Are you having a specific issue? have you tried anything or just wanted to ask a question before you gave it a shot?

Comment: I have tried adding through Ui and Dev console and neither have worked. I have created 100's of triggers in the past.

Comment: Define "neither have worked" If an error what was it verbatim. Are you trying to do this in a production org? Do you have correct permissions

Comment: You cant add triggers into production. I am adding through a sandbox as a System admin. I will get the error verbatim.

Comment: Thats why I asked (And BTW you can with an IDE just not via UI or Dev console )

Comment: My mistake. Must have fat fingered the trigger object in the developer console. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly still create triggers within Salesforce (in a sandbox) via the `Developer Console`. Just navigate to `File` > `New` > `Apex Trigger` and then select a name and object.

If you are not able to create a trigger through these means, verify that your user still has the **`Author Apex`** permission.

Comment: Yeah. I think I fat fingered the object when I was first trying to create the trigger. :( My mistake.